# How to extract a number/byte from an array in C?

Tags: c

Here i have written a code which produces next 8 numbers from sequence.

```
int next_exp_data(unsigned long long int expected_data)
{
  int i=0;
  unsigned long long int seq_gen_value=1976943448883713;
  unsigned long long int temp_data[10];
  temp_data[0]=seq_gen_value;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  { 
     printf("%llu",temp_data[i]);
     putchar('\n');
     expected_data=temp_data[i]; 
     temp_data[i+1]=temp_data[i] +2260630401189896;
  }
  return (expected_data);
}
```

I want to know how can i extract each  byte/number of the array and return each number/byte ??Please help me out.

EDIT:Here's my code.Basically i want to read a file and compare the contents to check if the data read matches with generated sequential data.Here the buffer contains same data as temp_data is producing(ie 10 numbers like 0x07060504030201 next 0f0e0d0c0b0a0908 etc).I want to comapre buffer's data and the function's data.Can anyone suggest me how can i do.I am stuck.Any changes are appreciated.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<inttypes.h>

 int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char *buffer,c;
    size_t filesize,buffer_size;
    int i;
    unsigned long long int expected_data=1976943448883713;
    fp=fopen("seqdata.c","r");
    if(fp==NULL){  
       fputs("Error\n",stderr);
       exit(1);
    }
    fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_END);
    filesize=ftell(fp);
        printf("Size of seqdata file is:%u \n",filesize); 
    fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET); 
    buffer=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);
    if(buffer == NULL){
        fputs("\nMemory error ",stderr);
    }
    buffer_size=fread(buffer,sizeof(char),filesize,fp);
    for(i=0;i<buffer_size;i++){
        printf("%c",*(buffer +i));
    }
    printf("No of elements read from file are:%u \n",buffer_size); 

    fseek(fp,0L,SEEK_SET);
    int current_pos = 0;
    while(current_pos < buffer_size){
         if(*(buffer +current_pos) != expected_data)
         {
           fputs("Error\n",stderr);
           exit(1);
         }
         else{
          printf("data matching \n"); 
          current_pos++;
          expected_data=next_exp_data(expected_data);
          }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;   
 }  

 int next_exp_data(unsigned long long int expected_data)
 {
   int i=0;
   unsigned long long int seq_gen_value=1976943448883713;
   unsigned long long int temp_data[10];
   temp_data[0]=seq_gen_value;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   { 
     printf("%llu",temp_data[i]);
     putchar('\n');
     expected_data=temp_data[i]; 
         temp_data[i+1]=temp_data[i] +2260630401189896;
}
return (expected_data);
 }
```

Comment: If you formatted your code better I'd be inclined to help. Just indent all lines by 4 spaces or a tab.

Comment: @Clark:I indented it.I want to take each number and compare character by character.

Comment: @Thej: You've posted a lot of code, but only two lines to explain what you want to do. I don't understand what you want to do, and it looks like I'm not the only one. If you explain clearly what the program should do, you will get better answers.

Comment: @Gilles:For testing purpose my seq_data.c file has same data as my function next_exp_data produces.I want to compare the contents of the file and the generator ie in this case the function.But i don't know how to compare.(its like generator and checker).I want to compare data present in the buffer and data produced by function.

Comment: basically i want of write a application in c which reads a file and checks the contents and gives the output if it data matches or not.

Comment: If you want to compare the contents of a file, why not just do a checksum? I'm sure there are a lot of cryptography libraries for C that you could use.

You could also read the two files into memory and use memcmp.

Comment: @Tangrs:I am not comparing two files.My application should be able to read the file and check if the data present matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's machine dependent, but this usually works one of two ways:

```
union {
    unsigned char b [8];
    long long     i;
} v;
v .i = seq_gen_value;
for (int j = 0;  j < 8;  ++j)
    printf ("%d, ", v .b [j]);
```

On a little endian machine (x86, vax, etc.) the bytes come out with the least significant first.  On a big endian machine, they come out with the most significant first.

---

By the way, it would be more useful to encode the "magic numbers" so that they can be more easily understood what they mean.  For example, instead of `1976943448883713`, write it as `0x7060504030201`.

Comment: @i have posted my code above.Can you help me out what changes can i make so that numbers returned from function can be compared??

Answer (score 0):

I think that your function do something like

```
return 1976943448883713 + 8 * 2260630401189896
```

And I think your question is not clear enough, like what array you want to return each its number? If you want to return array temp_data, it very easy. You can do that by

```
int next_exp_data(unsigned long long int expected_data, unsigned long long int temp_data[])
{
  int i=0;
  unsigned long long int seq_gen_value=1976943448883713;
  temp_data[0]=seq_gen_value;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  { 
     printf("%llu",temp_data[i]);
     putchar('\n');
     expected_data=temp_data[i]; 
     temp_data[i+1]=temp_data[i] +2260630401189896;
  }
  return (expected_data);
}
```

Call this function with the second params is a array int with size 10.
And another thing, I don't think that this function need the 1st param, because it's not be used within the function, so you can remove that from functions params list

```
int next_exp_data( unsigned long long int temp_data[])
{
  int i=0;
  unsigned long long int expected_data;
  unsigned long long int seq_gen_value=1976943448883713;
  temp_data[0]=seq_gen_value;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  { 
     printf("%llu",temp_data[i]);
     putchar('\n');
     expected_data=temp_data[i]; 
     temp_data[i+1]=temp_data[i] +2260630401189896;
  }
  return expected_data; //dont use (expected_data), it will make things slower.
}
```

Comment: dao:i have posted my code above.Can you help me out what changes can i make so that numbers returned from function can be compared??

Comment: I want expected_data to return single number.For ex-if temp_data produces 0x07060504030201.i want function to return 0 first time then 7 then 0 then 6 etc so that i can compare each number

Answer (score 0):

Comparing numbers in C is done using ==, !=, <= , >= , <, or >.

I didn't read your code as it's horrible formatted and doesn't seem relevant to your question as posed in the title.